# Bootstrap collapse panel going too big when expanding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my Collapse panel to work (new to this), and it now minimizes well, but when expanding, it expands right to the bottom of the page, and then returns to the expected size.

http://www.bootply.com/1OBli5zMTd

Click the little Expand/Collapse icon on the top right. Watch as it goes way too big, and then returns to the size it should.

How can I make it just expand to the right size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually not sure what was causing this, but I did find a solution. Move `#collapseClosed` outside of `.panel-group`. I think there is some strange nesting issue here with the default CSS, but I'd have to spend more time to figure out exactly what is wrong.

Here is your adjusted [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/PmCt9VHnuR) and also a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qf8q6xv/).